# Saving Cascading drop downs in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have cascading dropdowns in my MVC partial view. DD1 drives the values in DD2. When I select DD1 I want DD2 to be populated with, based on a DB table, the correct values based on DD1's value.

My thought was to make DD2 a partial view and nest in my form. Then, with ajax, I can tell the partial view to refresh and pass it the value of DD1.

The problem is, when I submit the whole view (with both DD1 and DD2 and a bucnh of other stuff, how do I get the value that is in DD2?

I'm trying to solve this problem using MVC, rather than triggering a javascript function on change of DD1 to make a JSON call to get the options and then using javascript to modify DD2 to the correct values.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

How big are your value sets for each drop down?

I was attempting to do this same thing a few years ago. DD1 was United States and Canada, and DD2 was the associated States and Provinces. If your data set is relatively small, you're better off just putting all the select list markup for both cases in the page, and then swapping it out with javascript (jQuery). You'll be saving yourself the request round trip, regardless of whether you go ajax or a full page refresh.

If the data set is large and it doesn't make sense to put all values in the markup, and you want to use MVC views instead of modifying the DOM with an ajax call, then just refresh the entire page. If you want to go ajax, then just modify the DOM with jQuery; you don't need a partial view to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use javascript unless you want to do an entire page postback. For this type of thing, javascript/ajax is the way to go.  I personally had a hard time when I switched to MVC having to accept that all this business logic was happening outside of the MVC model.  But in the end, it's whatever makes the website work best (user doesn't see your code and know how pretty it is).

Anyway, partials won't work either unless you post the whole page since without using javascript, the partial is rendered as part of that page/form.

I would just add a onchange event to the first dropdown that triggers a json call to a method in the same controller...something like

...jquery...

```
$("#mydropdown").change(function() {
    $.post("/Controller/DropdownChangedJSON", { firstdropdownvalue: $("#mydropdown").val() }, function(data) {
    $("#seconddropdown").empty();
    //    loop through "data" to populate dropdown
}); //post
}); //mydropdown_change()
```

and in your controller:

```
public JsonResult DropdownChangedJSON(string firstdropdownvalue) {
    //get results
    List<datamodel> myarray = //something
    return new JsonResult { Data = new { success = true, rows = myarray } };
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: So your saying if I have a partial view on my page called "Application". And I have 5 partial views inside of Application, that I can't submit the whole "Application" partial view at once and save all the data?

Comment: well, if you do it right.  In the parent view you wrap the "Application" partial with a html.BeginForm() - make sure there are no other form tags nested within any of those partials.  If your post ActionResult is expecting a model, the fieldnames need to match (case sensitive).All the fields within that top-level form should be available in the ActionResult - even if the fields were populated and manipulated with javascript/ajax.

Comment: So the nested partial Views need to have the same Model as the Application partial view?

Comment: Yea you do if you want to 1) to take advantage of MVC's validation, 3) if you want the validation to interact with invalid fields like highlight them 3) create the fields with the MVC helpers like <%: Html.TextboxFor(m=>m.FirstName)%> 4) be consistent with the MVC model - just to name a few =)  I know someone is going to read this and say "I can do all that without sticking with the MVC model!" - and I say "you're right!" - but these are just examples ;)